# how to fix apache server :(20014)Internal error : AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 127.0.0.1:5000

Tags: apache-2.4, flask

I use a flask server in apache.
run a script which prepare then download an xml file.
this is working fine is script
but if script lasts longer than 80 sec it's stopped and http error 502 is displayed and the xml file is not closed correctly and i get this message :

This page contains the following errors:
error on line 2373 at column 426: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

the log file report :

> Blockquote

2022-10-11 21:42:54 Error   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 502 GET /email/xxxxxxx.com HTTP/1.1     Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 1.68 K  Apache SSL/TLS access
2022-10-11 21:43:25 Error   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx         (20014)Internal error (specific information not available): AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 127.0.0.1:5000                Apache error
2022-10-11 21:43:25 Error   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx         AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /email/xxxxxx@xxxx.com                Apache error

> 

I have try the script directly in the server with ssh terminal and it's executed without any error.

the conf setting :
{<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all

ProxyPreserveHost On
<Location "/email">
ProxyPass "http://127.0.0.1:5000/email"
ProxyPassReverse "http://127.0.0.1:5000/email"

}
i have try some setting as :
retry=1 connectiontimeout=180  timeout=180 keepalive=on
but without result